# codeigniter regular expression for uri slug in routes

Tags: regex, codeigniter, routes, slug

I want to call a function from a controller, my_controller, passing in two arguments to some_method: first argument is the slug (ie. some-website-slug); second, a number. This is what I am trying:

```
$route['my_controller/([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*)/(:num)'] = "my_controller/some_method/$1/$2";
```

The problem is, it always passes in "-slug" (ie. the last part of the slug string) instead of the number. So for example with

base_url/my_controller/some-uri-slug/2

It will pass in "-slug" instead of the number 2. Is there something wrong with the regex or is it CI?

Comment: Try `$3` instead of `$2`

Comment: Cool, I posted as an answer if you want to mark correct.

Comment: You can use rubular.com to test your expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Regex has two pairs of `()`, so `(:num)` is actually at `$3` not `$2`.